# Automate java program execution task daily basis using shell script

Tags: java, shell

I need to automate the execution of java program (using build jar file) daily basis(every day). How can I do this task in a shell script without it stopping or finishing?

Comment: java -jar myjar.jar? But what's the problem? Execute it daily? Execute it itself?

Comment: Have you looked into using cron?

Comment: See https://www.programcreek.com/2009/08/schedule-a-task-to-a-certain-time-and-make-java-app-run-as-a-windows-service-using-java-service-wrapper/ for one possible solution for windows. For UNIX based systems, use cron.

Answer (score 2):

You can use crontab to execute your Java jar daily.  The code below will add the exeuction of your Jar into the crontab.  The contrab entry is configured to execute once a day.

```
#write out current crontab
crontab -l > mycron
#echo new cron into cron file
echo "0 0 * * * java -jar myjar.jar" >> mycron
#install new cron file
crontab mycron
rm mycron
```